# Column jumbling in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a grid in which there are 16 columns and 15th column will be
hidden when the status=sent,match or completed else it will be
visible.  so when the 15th column is hidden(visible-false) then 16th
colum which is a checkbox is coming into 15th colmn.

**code**

```
Protected Sub gvPOItems_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvPOItems.RowDataBound

    If _po.Status = "Completed" OrElse _po.Status = "Matched" OrElse _po.Status = "Sent" Then
         e.Row.Cells(15).Visible = False
```

[image: grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `Visible` property of the Cell to `false`, it dissapears from the HTML. That means that all the next cells shift one position to the left.

So it's better to just empty the cells or remove the controls, but keep them visible.

```
e.Row.Cells(15).Text = ""
//or
e.Row.Cells(15).Controls.Clear
```